# ASP.NET 4.5.2 MVC5 web api controller returning 404 on production server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an issue where my web api that works fine on my development machine is returning 404s for all routes when installed on the production server. The production server is running Windows 2008 (not R2) if this matters.

I've confirmed the correct framework is installed on said server (project is targeting 4.5.2)

I've tried the most suggested solution of adding:

`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` to `<system.webServer>`

but this does not work at all.

I also tried the other suggestion of adding the following instead of RAMMFAR:

```
<modules>
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
</modules>
```

But this also doesn't seem to work at all.

Any ideas what the issue here might be or other things I can try?

**Possibly irrelevant but perhaps related:**

One odd thing I found while looking into the UrlRoutingModule is that if I open server level in IIS Manager and view modules, it is listed in there, but if I try to change the "invoke only for requests to ASP.NET applications..." checkbox I get the following error, which almost seems to suggest it's not installed properly or something?  I tried a repair of the .net framework 4.5.2 on this basis but no luck with that either.

[image: UrlRoutingModule Error]